# Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am creating an Angular site dashboard for admin over my services and was curious to know if there is a way I can integrate a view of my Application Insight telemetry from Azure Mobile Apps? Is there a way to include my AI in an iframe or something similar? Sorry for the basic question but struggling to find info on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. You could use the AI Rest Api (it is in preview) and create your own dashboard components.  See https://dev.applicationinsights.io/.

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for :D Thank you